# sitemap formatting

Tags: format, sitemap

In the sitemaps.org was said that for a sitemap.xml located in http://example.com/catalog/ on the server URL https://example.com/catalog/page1.php is NOT valid (because all URLs listed in the Sitemap must use the same protocol)

Does the following code of sitemap is valid than?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">  
    <url>  
        <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>  
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>  
    </url>  
    <url>  
        <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/software/</loc>  
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>  
    </url>  
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following kink for validation:

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html